# Creating relationships of nodes of the same kind in Neo4j Cypher

Tags: dataframe, graph, neo4j, cypher

Here is a part from the dataframe that im working with:

```
A_PERSON, B_PERSON, MESSAGE_TIME
SARAH, RON, 13:20 pm
RON, TIM, 13:33 pm
TIM, MARTHA, 13:45 pm
RON, LARRY, 13:35 pm
LARRY, JIM, 13:38 pm
```

I want to create a graph that shows all the messages sent between these people, and the arrows should show the time of the message.

I've tried something like this:

```
load csv with headers 
from "file:\\df.csv" as row 
create(m: Message {a_person: row.A_PERSON, b_person: row.B_PERSON, time: row.MESSAGE_TIME})
```

so that later I could MATCH them but it doesn't seem possible. The result has some A_PERSON duplicates in it because of the second and third label. So I don't understand how to create unique nodes and connect them to each other.
Is it possible to do? And if it is, then how?

Answer (score 1):

The key to this is to use the `MERGE` clause. `MERGE` each person and then `MERGE` the relationship between the two people.

`MERGE` will create the person if they don't exist or `MATCH` them if they do.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM "file:\\df.csv" AS row 
MERGE (a_person:Person {name: row.A_PERSON})
MERGE (b_person:Person {name: row.B_PERSON})
MERGE (a_person)-[:SENT_MESSAGE {time: row.MESSAGE_TIME}]->(b_person)
```

or, if you anted message to be a node, you could do something like this.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM "file:\\df.csv" AS row 
MERGE (a_person:Person {name: row.A_PERSON})
MERGE (b_person:Person {name: row.B_PERSON})
MERGE (a_person)-[:SENT_MESSAGE]->(:Message {time: row.MESSAGE_TIME})-[:TO]->(b_person)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Dave Can you help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60560218/how-to-create-nodes-and-relationships-from-csv-in-neo4j ?